# Email Reminder to list of users - PHPMAILER, PDO, CRON?

Tags: php, pdo, cron, phpmailer

so now i've managed to make a script that works but it only reads and send an email to the first record on the list, am i missing a loop or foreach statement somewhere?

**Query:**

```
$query = "SELECT id FROM " . $this->table_name . " WHERE status = 'Confirmed' ";

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query );
    $stmt->execute();

    $num = $stmt->rowCount();

    return $num;
```

**Read & Email**

```
[QUOTE]if($total_rows>0){

        while ( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

            extract($row);
include_once 'phpmailer_script.php';
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question / problem that you're having?

Comment: This is rather broad but you would use cron to schedule when the reminders are sent using phpMailer. The code that does the mailing would use PDO to retrieve the data from your database.

Comment: Depending on how many emails would be sent on a single run, I would advice against using the built-in PHP function and instead try using an email delivery service such as Sendgrid or Mailgun (or many others) in order to achieve a better deliverability. You need to be aware that if the amount of emails is large enough for the process to take too long, you may need to pivot on a semaphore table and establish multiple worker processes to handle the work on multiple fast iterations rather than one (or few) slow ones that could eventually reach your servers time limit for execution

Comment: He's not using the built-in PHP function. You can use PHPMailer with any local or external mail server. When PHP is run from the command line, by default it does not have an execution time limit, and there is no browser waiting for the results. I have PHP processes running for weeks at a time like this. In my experience you can send between 25 and 500 messages per second (depending on message generation overhead & size) with PHPMailer to a nearby mail server, so you need to have really large volumes before you need to venture into multi-process architectures, though I have done that too.